# Error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended | Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, offset, sql-limit

I'm getting the error:

> Error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

When I run the following ORACLE query:

```
Select "col1", "col2" 
from SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME 
OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You are missing a double quote in the `select`.  If that is the cause of your problem, it is merely a typo.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are running Oracle < 12.2, where the `fetch` clause is not available.

A typical workaround uses window functions:

```
select col1, col2
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn
    from schemaname.tablename t
) t
where rn between 101 and 200;
```

Note that, for both your original query and this query to produce a stable result, you need a column that deterministically defines the ordering of the rows. I assumed `id`.

If you do want an unstable sort, which I would not recommend, then use `order by null` in the `over()` clause of `row_number()`.